# Select features interactively in ArcGIS WebAppBuilder Using a Widget

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I am looking to build a seemingly simple tool into my [WebAppBuilder](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/) Map.

Some basics:

- Content is created in ArcGIS 10.3.1
- Content is published to ArcGIS 10.3.1 Server as a Cached Service
- Map is developed on ArcGIS Online
- Map is pushed to WebAppBuilder
- Out-of-box widgets are used currently (have [developer version of WebAppBuilder](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/) so I can work with code to custom create if required)

The Task:To replicate the function of [Select Features Interactively](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-layers/selecting-features-interactively.htm) in WebAppBuilder.

[image]

To date I have tried using variations of the [Query Widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-query.htm) as it allows users to interactively select features by using the "Use Spatial Filter to Limit Features" and then the "Only Features Touching a User Defined Area" (see image below)

[image]

However, this has not proven successful as it is a variation of what I am seeking. I simply want the user to be able to select geometries (polygons, lines, points) and have them highlight on the map.

As a bonus - I am looking to have the user be able to control the color that highlights the selection - similar to the Selection Options. (see image below)

[image]

Comment: In ArcMap, a user would typically select some features in order to do something further with them. Does that apply in your web app? Aside from highlighting the features on the map, what is the intended purpose of 'selecting' the features?

Comment: @StephenLead the end goal is to have a user be able to select a feature to highlight that will show up on a printed map. The main idea here is to showcase the selected parcel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the Query Tool and manipulating it to achieve what I needed.

Comment: Good one! Thanks for the suggestion. Not elegant but works.